# Can't install dm-postgres-adapter

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sinatra

Following instructions on Heroku website, I've installed `Postgress.app`, installed `pg` gem, installed `data_mapper`, everything went smoothly. Finally, tried to install dm-sqlite-adapter and got this:

```
sudo gem install dm-postgres-adapter
Fetching: data_objects-0.10.14.gem (100%)
Successfully installed data_objects-0.10.14
Fetching: do_postgres-0.10.14.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing dm-postgres-adapter:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpq... yes
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for postgres.h... yes
checking for mb/pg_wchar.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pgsql-server-dir
    --without-pgsql-server-dir
    --with-pgsql-server-include
    --without-pgsql-server-include=${pgsql-server-dir}/include
    --with-pgsql-server-lib
    --without-pgsql-server-lib=${pgsql-server-dir}/
    --with-pgsql-client-dir
    --without-pgsql-client-dir
    --with-pgsql-client-include
    --without-pgsql-client-include=${pgsql-client-dir}/include
    --with-pgsql-client-lib
    --without-pgsql-client-lib=${pgsql-client-dir}/
    --with-pqlib
    --without-pqlib
Could not find PostgreSQL build environment (libraries & headers): Makefile not created


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/do_postgres-0.10.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/do_postgres-0.10.14/ext/do_postgres/gem_make.out
```

I also tried

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install dm-postgres-adapter
```

but with the same result.

I looked into gem_make.out and found in the end of it the following:

```
Could not find PostgreSQL build environment (libraries & headers): Makefile not created
```

Any advice on what to try?

Comment: I installed Postgres.app. That's a way to install PostgreSQL on a Mac. Digging into subfolders of the installation I can find the file that is reported to be missing, so I am trying to use various options, like `sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install dm-postgres-adapter -- --with-pgsql-server-include=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include/postgresql/server`, but so far no success.

Comment: Trying to figure out where to find it.

Comment: Well, I found it... But it isn't really helpful. It shows that all the headers were actually found successfully but there was a bunch of parsing errors, like this: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/include/postgresql/server/mb/pg_wchar.h:542:28: error: function cannot return function type 'bool' (aka 'int (int *)')
extern bool pg_utf8_islegal(const unsigned char *source, int length);
                           ^
2 warnings and 15 errors generated.`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was able to figure out.

The error messages, like can't find some headers or libraries, were misleading. All that stuff was found successfully, but, as mkmf.log shows, there were numerous parsing errors. That means there is a hiccup somewhere in the toolchain. I am on a Mac, so that could be a problem of either Xcode tools, or the version of Ruby, or some gems, or any of these just not working together on some reason... Who knows. I saw somewhere on the Stackoverflow someone with a similar problem managed to resolve it by reinstalling the whole toolchain.

I decided to choose a different path. I created a Ruby box on Nitrous.io, and there everything just worked so far - I was able to install PostgreSQL and the dreaded dm-postgres-adapter, and all the other gems I need. What a massive difference in experience.

It still doesn't resolve the problem of running Postgres.app and using it from Sinatra on my local machine, but I can live with that for now. Maybe one day I'll get angry enough to blast out the whole buggy toolchain and reinstall it again, but not yet, not yet...

Answer (score 0):

Hurray! I did it. And the solution is very simple: install Ruby 2.1.1. Then dm-postgres-adapter installs with no problem at all.